# Pig Latin: Loading a very simple Bag

Tags: hadoop, tuples, apache-pig, dump

I'm writing because today I bumped into a problem I can't solve in any way despite having searched everywhere and tried a lot of different statements.
I have this input file:

```
3 {(car pen house glass)}
5 {(battery phone)}
6 {(the)}
```

(I would like to clarify that I've added '(' and ')' to the original file because they were missing).
My goal is just to load this file (using LOAD) into a variable and dumping it (using DUMP).

I show below the attempts I made and their relative DUMP outputs:

```
wc = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (count:int,b:bag{(s:chararray)});

(3,)
(5,)
(6,{(the)})


wc = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (count:int,b:tuple(s:chararray));

(3,)
(5,)
(6,(the))


wc = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (count:int,b:bag{item:tuple(s:chararray)});

(3,)
(5,)
(6,{(the)})
```

Have you any idea to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using ' ' as the delimiter and the bag contains ' '.A workaround is to load the records into a line and then use STRSPLIT to split the line into 2 fields.

```
wc = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (line:chararray);
wc_new = FOREACH wc GENERATE STRSPLIT(line,' ',2);
DUMP wc_new;
```